# sql query to order the data

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to order the data in column for a table in one order that is i am having a table Person having age like

```
age
12
14
13
14
45
12
45
23
12
23
12
```

I want to group all the similar ages one after other.How to do this?I have tried using group by
select age from person group by age.This is not working for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT age FROM Person ORDER BY age
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Person ORDER BY age
```

Answer (score 0):

In `MySQL`, you can use `GROUP BY` without aggregating columns but in `oracle` you can't. Try it using `DISTINCT` so it will only select unique values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT age
FROM Person
Order by age ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought you want to join tables, in order to do that you have the following alternatives:

1) simple join with distinct/unique

```
select distinct person.name, age.age 
from person, age 
Where Person.Age = Age.Age 
order by age.age
```

Result:

```
person_5    12
person_3    14
person_1    23
person_4    23
person_2    45
```

2) right outer join

```
Select Distinct Person.Name, Age.Age 
from person right outer join age 
on Person.Age = Age.Age 
order by age.age
```

Result:

```
person_5    12
    null    13
person_3    14
person_1    23
person_4    23
person_2    45
```

3) left outer join

```
Select Distinct Person.Name, Age.Age 
from person left outer join age 
On Person.Age = Age.Age 
order by age.age
```

Result:

```
person_5    12
person_3    14
person_1    23
person_4    23
person_2    45
```

---

The source tables:
Person table(person and age column):

```
person_1    23
person_2    45
person_3    14
person_4    23
person_5    12
```

Age table (age column only):

```
12
14
13
14
45
12
45
23
12
23
12
```